# How to post image to Facebook wall with graph API

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, http-post

I want to post some text with image on Facebook wall. I have this code from graph API which does that but I want to post my image from bundle and not from a link as this API does. Can anyone tell me how to post your own image rather then the link

```
"[variables setObject:@"http://bit . ly/bFTnqd" forKey:@"link"];"
```

on Facebook wall.

```
NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:4];

[variables setObject:@"this is a test message: postMeFeedButtonPressed" forKey:@"message"];

UIImage *picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"forest fog.jpg"];
        
[variables setObject:@"http://bit . ly/bFTnqd" forKey:@"link"];
[variables setObject:@"This is the bolded copy next to the image" forKey:@"name"];
[variables setObject:@"This is the plain text copy next to the image.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy." forKey:@"description"];

    

FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"me/feed" withPostVars:variables];
NSLog(@"postMeFeedButtonPressed:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);

//parse our json
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
NSDictionary *facebook_response = [parser objectWithString:fb_graph_response.htmlResponse error:nil];   
[parser release];

//let's save the 'id' Facebook gives us so we can delete it if the user presses the 'delete /me/feed button'
self.feedPostId = (NSString *)[facebook_response objectForKey:@"id"];
NSLog(@"feedPostId, %@", feedPostId);
NSLog(@"Now log into Facebook and look at your profile...");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You covert Image into data and add that as another parameter (Data value for key "data") in the Dictionary.I have given sample here

```
[variables setObject:imageData forKey:@"data"];
```

Other Change

```
UIImage *picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"forest fog.jpg"];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(picture, 10);


NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"your caption message",@"message", 
                               imageData,@"data",
                               nil];

FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"me/photos" withPostVars:variables];
NSLog(@"postMeFeedButtonPressed:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);
```

Comment: I tried your code but its giving error "-[NSConcreteMutableData dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x70c09e0"

Comment: Do you want all the message , Description, link , all those fields or only image with Caption

Comment: And also Have you increased the Dictionary Capacity,
NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:5];

Comment: I have not increased the capacity as i have removed the link section and added your data code

Comment: Sorry but its giving error "-[NSConcreteMutableData dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x70c09e0" and crashing

Comment: In addition with the above change, channge the request with url like, 

FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"me/photos" withPostVars:variables];

Comment: Its also giving the same error and i have tried many things for eg:"FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"me/photos" withPostVars:variables];"  post images to a album and this will be my last option .but now i want to post image to wall

Comment: U just nail through tat..U can find it out.. For more on Graph API, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: hey pankaj kainthla, did you fix this issue? If so can you update the description above. I am also facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Following code should work to solve your problem...

```
    FBStreamDialog *dialog = [[[FBStreamDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
    dialog.attachment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"name\":\"Photo uploaded.\",\"description\":\"\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\"\",\"href\":\"%@/\"}]}",PhotoSourceURL];
    [dialog show];
```

Let me know, is it working for you or not...

**Edit:**

[**Try this one...**](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app)

Comment: This is from fbconnect but i wanted to use graph api