# Post picture to Facebook from iPhone/iPad app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have developed an app for the iPad and iPhone that uses the camera to take a picture

Can someone tell me the easiest way to publish that to a users Facebook page?

Do I need to use the Facebook api's?  I am not writing a Facebook app, just want to post the picture on the users wall.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Would not make sense not to use FB API. There might be some other API that uses FB API itself but not sure about that..

I found a similar question:
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951253/how-to-post-image-to-facebook-wall-with-graph-api)

Hope that helps!